# Creating x amount of pages equal to x ID's in database?

Tags: php, database

The title may be a little vague, but I'll try to explain the concept here.

I have a site in which daily new items ( sports games ), get published, now what I would love is that my users would be able to click on a certain game and get redirected to a new page with more detailed information about that one game.

The thing is, creating every php page seperate for every game each day is a lot of work because also a lot details in the page need to be changed. 
Now I was wondering if it is possible in some kind of way that there's a script that reads, OK you have 5 games today, page 1 = id number, title of the page is the matches name, extra info is the info that stands with that id.

I don't know how else to explain this so I hope this was good enough.

Thanks for your time and reading this :)

Comment: Just use $_GET to pass the id variable through the url

Comment: But then how do I check how many ID's there are in the database to pass each one of them? Just with a simple foreach or?

Comment: You don't have to pass them all, just the one you want to show the information

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests to select the page (the best way is to use $_GET as suggested by gbestard) to select the ID. Then you can have some static content (like url or short article or link to screen shot or something similar) stored in your database under the same ID as the game, and upon clicking on the link to the game, the page is reloaded and you populate it with the new content, that was stored in the database.

You can even store entire pages with static html (as in article or short game description in your case) content and etc in your database and simply call them to populate a div.

If you have something like a custom made admin section of your site, you can add a page to edits it with a js plugin like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and the creation/editing of articles will be a piece of cake.

It's pretty much a standard case of a CMS(Content management system).